# How to send push notification whenever a user sends a direct message to another user (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, push-notification, triggers, messaging

I am currently trying to make a messaging application on IOS, but I am stumped on the concept of getting my app to immediately send a push notification to a user when their friend sends them a message. I have been doing some research and I am seeing that triggers in MySQL to check when an insert is made, in conjunction with PHP to create the notification payload may be the right approach. My question is am I on the right track or is there a more sound way to go about performing this task?

Comment: The only solution is in create PHP polling procedure which executes periodically (from cron, for example), checks for new rows needed in notification sending, and did. *I am seeing that triggers in MySQL to check when an insert is made* No. They check nothing, they're a step of data change which is skipped if the trigger is not defined.

Comment: The alternative solution is not to use MySQL as the bridge between the two users, otherwise you are stuck with what @Akina wrote.

Comment: If I am not mistaken a cron job is done based on a set schedule correct? That would create an issue because I would want a notification sent instantly once a user sends a message to another user. Am I not understanding what you are saying or does the issue I mentioned exist? @Akina

Comment: What alternative aside of MySQL would be effective? @Shadow

Comment: *If I am not mistaken a cron job is done based on a set schedule correct?* No problems, use the procedure which works infinitely and checks for new messages as often as you need. Running from CRON is recommended to reduce server resource consumption - but this is not a dogma. Just don't forget to provide for restarting the procedure if its execution is interrupted for any reason.

Comment: So hypothetically if I made one cron job check every second would that cause any performance issues? @Akina

Comment: I don't know - test. Start from, for example, 10sec, and decrease this time slowly ensuring that the next job is not started when previous one is not finished yet.